# How can i process this form alone

Tags: jquery

I have this function on an html form, the form script there is this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           var conf = {
           isVip:false,
           isMem:false
        };
    </script>
```

and here is the the button, the button is to process two form in the html, here is the button.

```
 <li class="current">
  <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('process.php')">免费邮箱登录</a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('process.php')"><span class="vip"></span>VIPSubmit</a>
  </li>
 <a href="#" class="loginBtn"
```

Here is the form

```
       <form name="vip_login" method="post" action="process.php">
        <input tabindex="1" id="vipname" type="text" class="username" name="username" value=""/><span class="vipDomain">@name.com</span>
       <input  tabindex="2"  id="vippassword" type="password" class="password" name="password" value=""/>
```

My question is, how do i make the btn to process my form alone and send data to external process.php function.

Comment: What have you tried to far? You have tagged this question with jQuery but do not show any jQuery code or mention anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: It sounds like you should look into ajax, if I'm understanding

Comment: What does the `submitAction` function you have on your links look like?

Comment: dis is wot i have <a href="#" onclick="return false;">

Comment: Start by adding a SUBMIT button and a closing FORM tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have links not buttons. You need to make buttons with IDs.

```
<li class="current">
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="免费邮箱登录"></input>
</li>
<li>
    <input id="btn2" type="button" value="VIPSubmit"><span class="vip"></span></input>
</li>
```

Second, you can then use jQuery/AJAX to submit your form from clicking these buttons. You will need to add an ID to your form as well. Below, I made the ID the same as the 'name' attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("#vip_login").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url: "process.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#id on process.php").html(data); //If setting in process.php
                    window.alert("Data send");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Also note: Using AJAX, you do not need an "action" supplied in your form.

```
<form name="vip_login" id="vip_login" method="post" action="">
```

Comment: i have tried this, but when the submit button it not processing process.php, it still working as previous setting...<a href="#" class="loginBtn"

Comment: How are you accessing the data on process.php? That could be a problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, give the form an `id`:

```
<form id="vip_login" method="post" action="process.php">
```

Next, download jQuery if you don't already have it, and then setup the `onclick` of the `href` to be this:

```
<a href='#' class='loginBtn' onclick="$('#vip_login').submit();" ...
```

and that will force the submit of the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct

```
<form name="vip_login" method="post" action="process.php">
```

But you need to add a submit button, or use some javascript to do it, like

`document.vip_login.submit()`

You can add the previous after all validations are ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="loginBtn" onclick="document.forms['vip_login'].submit();"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add an `id` to your `<form>` so it would be something like this:

```
<form id="vip_login"  name="vip_login" method="post" action="process.php">
```

Then set the button's attributes to be like this:

```
<a href="#" class="loginBtn" onclick="document.getElementById('vip_login')).submit();">Submit</a>
```

This will get it to work, although the more elegant way to do it is to add a `submit` button within this form by adding the following element in your `<form>`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

Then if you click on this button the parent form will be submitted.